# How to use Sed to replace all characters before colon?

Tags: sed

How do I replace the following string

```
hd_ma_prod_customer_ro:*:123456789:john.doe
```

with
    john.doe

Basically I need to look for the last colon (:) and delete everything before and including it.

Answer (score 68):

Assuming what you actually mean is that you want to delete everything up to the last colon and leave the `john.doe` intact:

```bash
echo 'hd_ma_prod_customer_ro:*:123456789:john.doe' |
  sed 's/.*://'
```

#### Explanation:

First line just pipes the test string to `sed` for example purposes.

The second is a basic [`sed` substitution](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-1). The part between the first and second `/` is the regex to search for and the part between the second and third is what to replace it with (nothing in this case as we are deleting).

For the regex, `.` matches any character, `*` repeats this any number of times (including zero) and `:` matches a colon. So effectively it is anything followed by a colon. Since `.*` can include a colon, the match is 'greedy' and everything up to the last colon is included.

Answer (score 9):

Another method using `awk`:

```
awk -F: '{ print $NF }'
```

Answer (score 7):

```bash
sed -r 's/:/\t/g' filename | awk -F'\t' '{print $4}'
```

I am replacing all the occurrences of **:** with a **tab** and then using `awk` to extract the string john.doe.

If you do not have a file you can try this.

```bash
echo 'hd_ma_prod_customer_ro:*:123456789:john.doe' | sed -r 's/:/\t/g' | 
awk -F'\t' '{print $4}'
```

As per Graeme's comments we can use `awk` to print the last column alone using the `NF` variable of `awk` as below.

```bash
echo 'hd_ma_prod_customer_ro:*:123456789:john.doe' | sed -r 's/:/\t/g' | awk -F'\t' '{print $NF}'
```

**Incorporating Graeme's comments to get rid of unnecessary `sed`**

The command can be modified as below.

```bash
echo 'hd_ma_prod_customer_ro:*:123456789:john.doe' | awk -F':' '{print $NF}'
```

Comment: If you are going to use `awk`, why not just do `awk -F:`?

Comment: @Graeme, I am still not that comfortable with `awk`. Basically, I try to test the commands that I originally got in my answer and try to modify them according to the user's requirement. :)

Comment: The `-F` option for `awk` specifies the field separator. If you tell `awk` to use a colon, there is no need to replace the colons with tabs. Also, if you want to get the last field you can use `$NF` instead of `$4`, this would then work if there is not always 3 colons.

Comment: @Graeme, I have incorporated the changes you have mentioned. Please let me know if this is fine :)

Comment: Yes, works perfectly!

Comment: This is good information. Thank you guys for being so responsive.

Comment: If the field is actually at a fixed position, then don't use `$NF`. That means "the last field". Maybe it is more correct to use `$4` in this situation: the fourth field. (Could there ever be additional fields in the data? If so, will those additional fields be inserted before this last field, or after?) If the answer to the first question is no, then it doesn't matter whether you use `$4` or `$NF`; if the answer is yes, then it matters.

Answer (score 4):

Please try

```
echo 'abc:fjk' |sed 's/.*:/john.doe/g'
```

and to delete

```
echo 'abc:fjk' |sed 's/.*://g'
```

Comment: that's not what the OP's asking for

Comment: please re-read the question again.

Comment: Well you snuck in the delete after my comment, never mind

Comment: oh i see . my apologies 1_CR

Comment: The `^`anchor makes no difference in either the question's case or in your example case. Any address beginning with `/.*` already implies the `^`.